# Spring Boot Soap Web-Service (Java) - code first?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

I want to make a SpringBoot Application in Java with the following Soap Web-Service:

```
@WebService
public class HelloWorld
{
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name)
    {
        return "Hello world, " + name;
    }
}
```

I want to get the WSDL...
I think I have to create endpoints or mapping the service? How can I do that?

Without spring-boot it works, because the file in the WEB-INF folder with the code:

```xml
<endpoints xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime' version='2.0'>
    <endpoint name='HelloWorld' implementation='web.service.soap.HelloWorld' url-pattern='/HelloWorld'/>
</endpoints>
```

and

```xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add spring-boot-starter-ws and org.apache.cxf cxf-bundle dependency to your project.

And create a configuration file to expose your web services. Example of such config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class WebServicesConfig {
    @Autowired
    private HelloWorld helloWorld; // your web service component

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean wsDispatcherServlet() {
        CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, "/services/*");
    }

    @Bean(name="cxf")
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint helloWorldEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), helloWorld);
        endpoint.publish("helloWorld");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

To access your wsdl: http://localhost:8080/services/helloWorld?wsdl (path may be different)

Comment: Using this approach the endpoints are not actual beans manageable by spring. Annotate (at)WebService with (at)Component or (at)Service